# inherited class properties order

Tags: c#, inheritance, epplus

I have 2 classes, where one of them inherits from the other:

```
public class First
{
public string a{get;set;}
public string b{get;set;}
}
public class Second: First
{
public string c {get;set;}
}
```

Then i create a `List<Second>` and fill with some information, and then i export this list to an Excel using EPPlus.
But the "problem" is that the properties of the inherited class(Second) appears first and those of the base class(First) after in the excel:

```
c     |  a    |   b
-------------------
```

The question is whether i can put the properties of the base class first, or can i say to EPPlus the order of the properties?

EDIT:

I put the code to create the Excel, is very simple

```
:

 using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(archivo))            
{
 ExcelWorksheet ws= package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Solds");
 {
   ws.Cells["A3"].LoadFromCollection(lstSolds);
   package.Save();
 }

}
```

Comment: sure you can tell EPPlus the order of fields you want, paste the code you are using to export to excel

Comment: Well the code is more complex, because the class is big and the Excel have multiple Workseets, but i edit the cuestio and will put something.

Comment: just paste a sample of it, not necessarily the whole thing

Comment: I put the more basic of the code, in my code i have styles and other things,. I've been thinking about what you said about ordering, but i dont know how to do it, i know yo can sort the information by certain columns..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, more "Epplus" way I guess you could say, would be something like this:

```
var lstSolds = new List<First>();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lstSolds.Add(new Second
    {
        a = "A-" + i,
        b = "B-" + i,
        c = "C-" + i
    });
}

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(archivo)) 
{
    var mi = typeof (Second)
        .GetProperties()
        .OrderBy(pi => pi.Name)  //This controls the column order
        .Cast<MemberInfo>()
        .ToArray();

    ws.Cells["A3"]
        .LoadFromCollection(
            lstSolds
            , true
            , TableStyles.Custom
            , BindingFlags.Default
            , mi
        );

    package.Save();
}
```

You can control the order of the columns by adjusting the `mi` collection order.  In this case it is ordered ascending but any order set will be respected by `LoadFromCollection`.

[image]

---

**Response to Comments**

Its easy to have them sort in any order you need.  Just need to build the array before passing in a way that guarantees sort order.  Say we add a property `d` to the `First` class.  We can make sure it sorts before `c` like this:

```
public class First
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }  //Say we need this to sort before 'c'
}
public class Second : First
{
    public string c { get; set; }
}

...

var lstSolds = new List<First>();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    lstSolds.Add(new Second
    {
        a = "A-" + i,
        b = "B-" + i,
        c = "C-" + i,
        d = "D-" + i,
    });
}

using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("table");

    //var mi = typeof(Second)
    //    .GetProperties()
    //    .OrderBy(pi => pi.Name)  //This controls the column order
    //    .Cast<MemberInfo>()
    //    .ToArray();

    var firstmi = typeof (First)
        .GetProperties()
        .OrderBy(pi => pi.Name);

    var secondmi = typeof (Second)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => !firstmi.Select(fpi => fpi.Name).Contains(pi.Name))
        .OrderBy(pi => pi.Name);

    //Sorting above will keep first proper before second
    var mi = firstmi
        .Concat(secondmi)
        .Cast<MemberInfo>()
        .ToArray();

    ws.Cells["A3"]
        .LoadFromCollection(
            lstSolds
            , true
            , TableStyles.Custom
            , BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
            , mi
        );

    package.Save();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I like it very much, is very simple and for the example i put is perfectly valid and it has the advantage that this way I can reuse  "My " because I export the list more than once and this way I do not need to rewrite the code for every time I export the list , But in my program I can not sort them alphabetically because what I want is to go first the properties of a parent class (first) and then the properties of the inherited Class (second), because some properties names of the inherited class (second) Alphabetically they would go first, while others would go after.

Comment: @Ion  If I get what you are saying, that is very easy to do.  See my edits above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use attributes and reflexion to select the order of the properties. It also allow to select which properties you want to output or not

```
public class First {
    [Order(1)]
    public string a { get; set; }
    [Order(2)]
    public string b { get; set; }
}
public class Second : First {
    [Order(3)]
    public string c { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class OrderAttribute : Attribute {
    public int Order {get; set; }
    public OrderAttribute(int order) {
        Order = order;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Second> list = new List<Second>();
        list.Add(new Second {
            a = "a",
            b = "b",
            c = "c"
        });
        WriteList(list);
    }

    static void WriteList(List<Second> list) {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Second).GetProperties();
        int row = 3;
        int col = 0;
        foreach (var item in list) {
            Dictionary<int, object> values = new Dictionary<int, object>();
            foreach (var pi in properties) {
                var orderAttr = pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(OrderAttribute)) as OrderAttribute;
                if (orderAttr != null) {    //this allow to output selective propertes. Those properties without [order] attriburte will not output
                    values.Add(orderAttr.Order, pi.GetValue(item, null));
                }
            }
            foreach (var key in values.Keys.OrderBy(x => x)) {
                ws.Cells[row, col + key].Value = values[key];
            }
            row++;
        }
    }
```

Edited as @Ion comments, added function to read from Excel

```
    static List<Second> ReadFromExcel(string filePath) {
        List<Second> result = new List<Second>();
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Second).GetProperties();

        //Allow access propertyInfo by name
        Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (var pi in props) {
            properties.Add(pi.Name, pi);
        }


        using (var xls = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath))) {

            ExcelWorksheet ws = xls.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

            //Let's assume you have property names has row heading in Excel
            List<string> names = new List<string>(3);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                names.Add(ws.Cells[1, i].Value.ToString());
            }

            //Fill the list from Excel
            for (int row = 3; row <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; row++) {
                Second second = new Second();
                for (int col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
                    object value = ws.Cells[row, col].Value;
                    if (value != null)
                        properties[names[col]].SetValue(second, value);
                }
                result.Add(second);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This Works fine, the only thing is that row++ must be out of the last foreach and put ws.Cells[row, col +key] . Another question, if i want to put this values into a List<Second> again how ca i do it,?, i see there is option in the GetProperties like SetValue but not idea about how it Works.